# What is wrong with my Code (SendPingAsync)

Tags: c#

Im writing a `C#` Ping-Application.
I started with a `synchronous` Ping-method, but I figurred out that pinging several server with one click takes more and more time.
So I decided to try the `asynchronous` method.

Can someone help me out?

```
public async Task<string> CustomPing(string ip, int amountOfPackets, int sizeOfPackets)
{
    // timeout
    int Timeout = 2000;
    // PaketSize logic
    string packet = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfPackets; j++)
    {
        packet += "b";
    };
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(packet);
    // time-var
    long ms = 0;
    // Main Method
    using (Ping ping = new Ping())
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPackets; i++)
        {
            PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, Timeout, buffer);
            ms += reply.RoundtripTime;
        };
    return (ms / amountOfPackets + " ms");
};
```

I defined a "Server"-Class (Ip or host, City, Country).

Then I create a "server"-List:

```
List<Server> ServerList = new List<Server>()
            {
                new Server("www.google.de", "Some City,", "Some Country")
};
```

Then I loop through this list and I try to call the method like this:

```
foreach (var server in ServerList)
ListBox.Items.Add("The average response time of your custom server is: " + server.CustomPing(server.IP, amountOfPackets, sizeOfPackets));
```

Unfortunately, this is much more competitive than the `synchronous` method, and at the point where my method should return the value, it returns

> System.Threading.Tasks.Taks`1[System.string]

Comment: Please add your code where you are calling this method. If the method in which this method is called is not an `async` method, you will need to use `CustomPing.Result` to run the async method as a synchronous method.

Comment: Multitasking of any kind is indeed way more complicated the simple synchronous progamming. It is the big programming challenge of our days. Unfortuantely it am very uncertain if it can even solved down to a simple answer. As for getting started in Multitasking, I advise towards the (t)rusty background worker. It is old and still uses seperate threads 100% of the time but it really helps getting a handle on the patterns.

Comment: Is the return value the string representation of the object rather than the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have an async method it will return the task when it is called like this:

```
Task<string> task = server.CustomPing(server.IP, amountOfPackets, sizeOfPackets);
```

when you add it directly to your `ListBox` while concatenating it with a string it will use the `ToString` method, which by default prints the full class name of the object. This should explaint your output:

> System.Threading.Tasks.Taks`1[System.string]

The `[System.string]` part actually tells you the return type of the task result. This is what you want, and to get it you would need to await it! like this:

```
foreach (var server in ServerList)
   ListBox.Items.Add("The average response time of your custom server is: " + await server.CustomPing(server.IP, amountOfPackets, sizeOfPackets));
```

1) this has to be done in another `async` method and

2) this will mess up all the parallelity that you are aiming for. Because it will wait for each method call to finish.

What you can do is to start all tasks one after the other, collect the returning tasks and wait for all of them to finish. Preferably you would do this in an async method like a clickhandler:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<string> [] allTasks = ServerList.Select(server => server.CustomPing(server.IP, amountOfPackets, sizeOfPackets)).ToArray();
    // WhenAll will wait for all tasks to finish and return the return values of each method call
    string [] results = await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
    // now you can execute your loop and display the results:
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        ListBox.Items.Add(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: I modified the solution and it works fine, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The class `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>` is a helper class for Multitasking. While it resides in the Threading Namespace, it works for Threadless Multitasking just as well. Indeed if you see a function return a task, you can usually use it for any form of Multitasking. Tasks are very agnostic in how they are used. You can even run it synchronously, if you do not mind that little extra overhead of having a Task doing not a lot.

Task helps with some of the most important rules/convetions of Multitasking:

- Do not accidentally swallow exceptions. Threadbase Multitasking is notoriously good in doing just that.
- Do not use the result after a cancelation

It does that by throwing you exceptions in your face (usually the Aggregate one) if you try to access the [Result Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_Result) when convention tells us you should not do that.

As well as having all those other usefull properties for Multitasking.